# Sharing a link and or uploading a photo on facebook using actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook

Developing a flash based image editing application and I want to be able to share and or save edited images to facebook.

Do I need to get a API Key to upload photos?
What if I simply want to share a link with my friends? Do I still need an API key?
Can someone point me to examples and or tutorials?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do all of the things you want using the new Facebook [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api). You will need an API key. There is an official [ActionScript API for facebook](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Flash/ActionScript) and a [get started guide](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/facebook/) from Adobe.

The actual library you need is available on [google code](http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/).

Comment: Facebook Graph API uses OAuth and facebook-actionscript-api uses the old authentication method.